# MariaDB Error: Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the correct syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

```php
function userlogin() {
global $CURUSER;
unset($GLOBALS["CURUSER"]);

$ip = getip(); //$_SERVER["localhost"];
$nip = ip2long($ip);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bannedip WHERE $nip>= first AND $nip<= last") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
  ...
```

This is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '>= first AND <= last' at line 1

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products, and your code & error message say quite clearly MySQL.

Comment: You probably intend `first` and `last` to be certain variables, but besides that you really should use a prepared statement.

Comment: Please don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions! As it's deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Can you post the table structure for bannedip?  Are first and last columns in the table or other variables?